# Generate new values only when necessary (Flux/Flowable.generate & sample)

Tags: java, rx-java2, project-reactor

Is there a way to generate new values only when they are really needed?

In the following example, new values are generated all the time even though only one value is used per second. I know that I could use `interval` instead, but I would like the consumer to control the rate.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.<Integer>generate(emitter -> {
        // System.out.println("Generate");
        emitter.next(1);
    })
            .sampleFirst(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Amongst other things, I have tried `.publish(1).autoConnect()` but it didn't make a difference.

**Edit:** I am also interested in a solution for RxJava.

Comment: What do you mean by consumer control? Your example doesn't have much backpressure. Interval+onBackpressureLatest+map is a straightforward solution.

Comment: Let's say we have a service with a getResourceFlowable method. The flowable allows the user of the service (consumer) to keep track of a resource. Since the resource is not evented, its state has to be polled, which is expensive. There are different use cases which need different intervals. At first, I used Flowable.interval and let the user pass an interval to getResourceFlowable. This made the signature confusing (because there is also a second interval) and I thought it would be nicer if the user of the service could control the rate with a method like sampleFirst/throttleFirst.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution seems to be this one:

```
    Flux.<Integer>generate(emitter -> {
        System.out.println("Generate");
        emitter.next(1);
    })

            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I just don't like that the delays can add up.

**Edit:** Actually, delayElements is not an alternative for sampleFirst since it also delays the first element (which I want to receive immediately).

**Edit:** Interestingly, the same does not work in RxJava:

```
    Flowable.<Integer>generate(emitter -> {
        System.out.println("Generate");
        emitter.onNext(1);
    })

            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This will just delay the storm by one second.

Comment: Delay shifts the flow by the given time since day 1. The reactor equivalent operator is the spanout() in RxJava 2 Extensions.

Comment: Does it slow down the producer similar to Flux.delay? It does not seem to accept a buffer size as an argument (which I could set to 1).

Comment: `spanout` doesn't interfere with backpressure, you could use `rebatchRequests(1)` after spanout.

Comment: Thank you. It looks already better, but there is still a problem. For example, if I want to get an element every 5 minutes, it will generate an element and then wait for 5 minutes before delivering it. Instead, I would like to receive a fresh element every five minutes (as well as one immediately at the beginning). In this regard, throttleFirst is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Then you are back to `interval()`.

Comment: But how should I use `interval` if the `Flowable` creation is separated from the code where I want to configure the throughput (as explained in the comment on the question above)? With `rebatchRequests(1).zipWith(Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)...` I also get old elements.

Comment: What is this source you can't change? If you can only talk to this source via backpressure requests, there are no standard operators that would request for you only on a timer tick. You'd have to implement a custom operator for that and also make sure you don't put other operators between it and the source that modulate backpressure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164102/discussion-between-joel-richard-and-akarnokd).